Problem in ggplot2 with color and shape variables combining into a concatenated legend
So I have a plot which I'm trying to have the points colored by type1 and the shape shaped by note1 etc. For some reason, the plot is concatenating the dang things into a key like this:
type1
note1
- - - - (border value name, 1)
------ (another value name, 1)
* (apple, blue)
O (orange, red)

Here's a bad picture of how I want it to be instead:

etc and I want it to just have the names of the variables, not the combination/concatenation of both things in text. When I used an AI chatbot I got a great solution, but the solution doesn't actually work in my code so far as I have tried it. The AI recommended solution (thats not working):
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# Sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  groupID = rep(1:10, each = 3),
  AttributeValue = rnorm(30),
  type1 = rep(c("Single Observation", "Multiple Observations"), 15),
  note1 = rep(c("specific time", "shift", "notation", "interesting"), length.out = 30),
  MaterialNumber = sample(1000:9999, 30, replace = TRUE),
  MaterialName = sample(LETTERS, 30, replace = TRUE),
  date = sample(seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2023-01-01'), by="day"), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

# Create ggplot
p1 <- data %>%
  mutate(groupID = fct_reorder(as.factor(groupID), date)) %>%
  mutate(MaterialInfo = paste(MaterialNumber, "-", MaterialName)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = groupID, y = AttributeValue)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ note1, scales = "free", ncol = 2) + 
  labs(x = "groupID") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, vjust = 0.5, margin = margin(0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, "cm"))) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(
    color = note1,
    shape = type1,
    stroke = ifelse(type1 == "Multiple Observations", 0.5, 1),
    text = paste("SKU:", MaterialInfo,
                 "<br>groupID:", groupID,
                 "<br>date:", date,
                 "<br>Attribute Value:",  AttributeValue)),
    show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Multiple Observations" = 1, "Single Observation" = 16)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("specific time" = "#ffc425", 
                                "shift" = "#00b159", 
                                "notation" = "#d11141", 
                                "interesting" = "#f37735")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1, override.aes = list(shape = NA)), 
         shape = guide_legend(order = 2))

# Convert to plotly
p1_plotly <- ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text")

# Display plot
p1_plotly 

However, when I try this with my code I still can't get it to work:
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

# Sample data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  groupID = rep(1:10, each = 3),
  AttributeValue = rnorm(30),
  type1 = rep(c("Single Observation", "Multiple Observations"), 15),
  note1 = rep(c("specific time", "shift", "notation", "interesting"), length.out = 30),
  objectNumber = sample(1000:9999, 30, replace = TRUE),
  objectName = sample(LETTERS, 30, replace = TRUE),
  date = sample(seq(as.Date('2022-01-01'), as.Date('2023-01-01'), by="day"), 30, replace = TRUE)
)

# Create ggplot
p1 <- data %>%
  mutate(groupID = fct_reorder(as.factor(groupID), date)) %>%
  mutate(objectInfo = paste(objectNumber, "-", objectName)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = groupID, y = AttributeValue)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ note1, scales = "free", ncol = 2) + 
  labs(x = "groupID") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8, vjust = 0.5, margin = margin(0.25, 0, 0.25, 0, "cm"))) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(
    color = note1,
    shape = type1,
    stroke = ifelse(type1 == "Multiple Observations", 0.5, 1),
    text = paste("SKU:", objectInfo,
                 "<br>groupID:", groupID,
                 "<br>date:", date,
                 "<br>Attribute Value:",  AttributeValue)),
    show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Multiple Observations" = 1, "Single Observation" = 16)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("specific time" = "#ffc425", 
                                "shift" = "#00b159", 
                                "notation" = "#d11141", 
                                "interesting" = "#f37735")) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(order = 1, override.aes = list(shape = NA)), 
         shape = guide_legend(order = 2))

# Convert to plotly
p1_plotly <- ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text")

# Display plot
p1_plotly


Help is appreciated, thank you

Your example legend only has two keys for "note1" but there are four distinct values in that column?  Also, if you run data %>% mutate(groupID = fct_reorder(as.factor(groupID), date)) %>%   mutate(objectInfo = paste(objectNumber, "-", objectName)) %>%  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = groupID, y = AttributeValue)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ note1, scales = "free", ncol = 2) note the warnings. I believe your issue is with how you are trying to represent your data rather than with the functions themselves. Please add an example of what you are expecting the plot to look like (hand-drawn is fine).

It maybe easier to just use plot_ly instead of passing off a ggplot object
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(plotly)

  



clean = data |>
janitor::clean_names() |>
  mutate(group_id = fct_reorder(as.factor(group_id), date),
         material_info = paste(material_number, '-', material_name),
         labs_plot = glue::glue('SKU: {material_info} <br>
                                 groupID: {group_id} <br>
                                 Attribute Value: {attribute_value}'))



pal = c('#ffc425', '#00b159', '#d11141', '#f37735')

pal = setNames(pal, c('specific time', 'shift', 'notation', 'interesting'))


plot_ly(data = clean,
         x = ~group_id,
         y = ~attribute_value,
         text = ~labs_plot) |> 
  add_markers(
              type = 'scatter',
              mode = 'markers',
              symbol = ~type1,
              symbols = c('o', 'circle'),
              color = I('black')) |> 
  add_markers(type = 'scatter',
              mode = 'markers',
              color = ~note1,
              colors = pal)


Alternatively ggiraph does a pretty good job with the existing ggplot object all you have to do is sub in _interactive
library(ggiraph)



p = ggplot(clean, aes(x = group_id, y = attribute_value,
                      color = note1, shape = type1, tooltip = labs_plot)) +
  geom_point_interactive() +
  scale_shape_manual_interactive(values = c("Multiple Observations" = 1, "Single Observation" = 16)) +
  scale_color_manual_interactive(values = c("specific time" = "#ffc425", 
                                            "shift" = "#00b159", 
                                            "notation" = "#d11141", 
                                            "interesting" = "#f37735"))


girafe(ggobj = p)


Created on 2024-11-26 with reprex v2.1.1

This is amazing thanks so much! I'm going through and trying the 2nd option first and got this error which is wild:
ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text", height = ceiling(length(get_data()$var_names)/2) * 375)
Warning in geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
geom_GeomInteractivePoint() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
Please open an issue with your example code at
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
Warning in geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[2L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]).....

And this: Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'plotly_build' applied to an object of class "c('girafe', 'htmlwidget')"
101: plotly_build
98: getFromNamespace("prepareWidget", "plotly")
97: shinyRenderWidget
96: func
83: renderFunc
82: output$viz_run_chart
1: runApp

So if you go with the ggiraph option girafe makes the plot interactive for you! So naturally plotly will freak out a bit. I just rendered it via reprex so it is kind of hard to tell that it interactive. Sorry about that

oh so I dont need to pop it into plotly, I can just leave it as you have it? Thanks so much, this problem has absolutely melted my brain haha

Yeah after girafe(ggobj = p) it will be interactive

You really saved my bacon here, thanks so much! I also had to change the plotlyOutput() in the ui file to girafeOutput(), for anyone reading this later.
